# Updating fields on change of another field in Android MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I want to implement, let's say temperature unit converter. I want to do this using android MVVM and data binding, but I dont know how. 
I have a fragment which consists of three EditText fields: Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin. After changing one of these, the rest should automaticaly get updated. Without databinding, I set TextWatcher to each field and in onTextChanged I do all the validation and conversion logic and set value of other fields. In beforeTextChanged I removed listeners to the others fields, and in afterTextChanged set them again, to avoid infinite loop when one field gets updated, triggers TextWatcher which updates another field and so on...

This is simplified code of how I've achieved that without databinding.

```java
celsiusEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        fahrenheitEditText.removeTextChangedListener(fahrenheitEditTextWatcher);
        kelvinEditText.removeTextChangedListener(kelvinEditTextWatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        double celsius = String.valueOf(celsiusEditText.getText());
        double fahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);
        double kelvin = celsiusToKelvin(celsius)

        fahrenheitEditText.setText(Double.toString(fahrenheit));
        kelvinEditText.setText(Double.toString(kelvin));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        fahrenheitEditText.addTextChangedListener(fahrenheitEditTextWatcher);
        kelvinEditText.addTextChangedListener(kelvinEditTextWatcher);
    }
};
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: So, whats you issue? whats going on wrong in it?

Comment: I want to do the same using databinding, having separate Fragment, ViewModel and Model class.

Comment: seperate fragments means? 3 edit texts on 3 fragments? can you please explain your complete question a bit more understandable?

Comment: your question is like, you just saying what you are trying to do, not `what you actually want`

Comment: I want to update other fields when user edit one of them (all of them are in one fragment, say ConverterFragment). And it worked with textWatchers, but now I want my app using databinding and MVVM, where I have ConverterFragment, ConverterViewModel with TemperatureModel LiveData and Model holding values for temperature fields. And the problem is that I dont know how to combine databinding with textWatchers or maybe there is other solution than textWatcher with databinding to achieve that result.

Comment: just bing edittext `Text` property with getter n setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very simple solution. Here, let A and B are EditTexts that needs to sync when one has text changed by user input. At the same time each of their corresponding LiveData are updated:

### Activity

```
package marabillas.loremar.edittextmvvm;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AViewModel viewModel;
    private AListener aListener = new AListener();
    private BListener bListener = new BListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText a = findViewById(R.id.aEdit);
        final EditText b = findViewById(R.id.bEdit);

        viewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(getViewModelStore(), new ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(AViewModel.class);

        a.addTextChangedListener(aListener);
        b.addTextChangedListener(bListener);

        viewModel.isFieldsSynced = false;

        viewModel.aEditData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                if (!a.getText().toString().equals(s)) {
                    a.setText(s);
                }

                if (viewModel.isFieldsSynced) {
                    viewModel.isFieldsSynced = false;
                } else {
                    viewModel.isFieldsSynced = true;
                    b.setText("A changed");
                }
            }
        });

        viewModel.bEditData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                if (!b.getText().toString().equals(s)) {
                    b.setText(s);
                }

                if (viewModel.isFieldsSynced) {
                    viewModel.isFieldsSynced = false;
                } else {
                    viewModel.isFieldsSynced = true;
                    a.setText("B changed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class AListener implements TextWatcher {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            System.out.println("A text Changed");
            viewModel.aEditData.setValue(s.toString());
        }
    }

    class BListener implements TextWatcher {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            System.out.println("B text changed");
            viewModel.bEditData.setValue(s.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
package marabillas.loremar.edittextmvvm;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class AViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public boolean isFieldsSynced = false;
    public MutableLiveData<String> aEditData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> bEditData = new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

The first `if` logic is to determine if A is to be updated. The second `if` logic is to determine if B is to be updated. Here A is the EditText who's text is changed by user input. B is the EditText who's text needs to sync with A. This pair of logic makes sure that EditText and LiveData are updated only once.